# MySQL problema al introducir datos en una llave foránea

Tags: mysql

la cuestión es que tengo 2 tablas, equipos y clientes. El problema que estoy teniendo es que no puedo poner el numero correcto de los idcliente(que es una llave foranea) referenciada a id_cliente de la tabla clientes. No se porque pero al momento de seleccionar un elemento aparece en forma de 1-nombre_cliente en vez de solo el numero.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La pregunta no se entiende, por más imágenes que pongas. Por favor, escribe en la pregunta el mensaje de error que tienes, y cómo están formadas las tablas, lo puedes obtener con un `SHOW CREATE TABLE nombreDeLaTabla`.  **Copias el texto y lo pegas en la pregunta, no las imágenes, que sirven de casi nada para casos como este**.

Comment: No es un error. Quiero que cuando me deje seleccionar el idcliente(cuarta imágen) me aparezca solo el id, el número, no todo con el nombre. Fijate que pone: 1- Juan Martinez. Yo quiero que sólo diga 1.